# How to populate textbox control with timepicker value on close event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timepicker

I'm using a jQuery timepicker addon found [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), and I'm having some issues getting the value to populate upon closing the timepicker, mainly because the close event isn't included in the documentation.

Here's my initialization script, which is contained in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    showSecond: false,
    timeFormat: "hh:mm TT"
});
```

How can I populate the textbox with the current value upon closing this timepicker?

Comment: Just the same as onClose of datepicker, see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aarryy pointed out, the `onClose` event that's present in [the jQueryUI DatePicker documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) is the way to go.

```
onClose: function (dateText) {
    $(this).val(dateText);
}
```